# BreezeJS count of expanded entities

Tags: breeze

This is using BreezeJS and a Breeze controller through to an EF provider.  I have a couple of related Entities, lets call them Customer, which has a Navigation Property called Orders which links to a set of Order Entities for that customer.

What I'd like to display on the UI is a summary of Order Counts for a set of customers who match a partial name search.  I can do this through returning all the Order objects, but they're quite large objects and I don't really want to return 100's of them when I don't have to.  The inlineCount() method seems to always give the count of the top-level entity (Customer) rather than of the sub-Entities, no matter where I place it in the statement.

```
var predicate = breeze.Predicate.create('displayName', 'contains', partialName);         
return this.entityQuery.from('Customers')
        .where(predicate)
        .orderBy('displayName')
        .using(this.manager)
        .expand('Orders')
        .execute();
```

The documentation suggests that you can chain the expand in some way, but I have yet to find a syntax which is valid.

Ideally, I'd like to apply a where to the Orders by a property on Order called Status of say 0 (incomplete) and then give me just the count of those matching Orders.  ie, return me all the Customer entities, but have a matching order count for each (rather than the whole list of Order objects and filter client-side).

Would appreciate any pointers in the right direction if it's possible to achieve.  My current thinking is that I'll have to create a custom method on the server-side controller and do the work there, but before I make assumptions about what OData can support, I thought I'd check here for some confirmation.

Comment: Obviously one option would be to get back all Customers which match the 1st predicate and then do another query client-side for all Order entities which have a matching customer.id and a status of 0.  So far, that's proving quite slow though when there's a lot of customers matching the name, so looking for suggested options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, this is my best approach (maybe someone can correct me if there's a better way).

On the server, add this method:

```
  public IQueryable<object> CustomerSummaries()
  {
     return Context.Customers.Select(p => new
                                          {
                                             Customer = p,
                                             ActiveOrderCount = p.Orders.Count(o => o.Status == 1)
                                          });
  }
```

Then on the client end:

```
     var predicate = breeze.Predicate.create('customer.displayName', 'contains', partialName);

     return this.entityQuery.from('CustomerSummaries')
        .where(predicate)
        .using(this.manager)
        .execute();
```